# How can I run multiple windows form from one in C#?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

how can run for example 20 windows forms, from one form with threads?
Browse is my new form and i want to create 20 number of this form

```
 Browser Browse = new Browser();
 Browse.Show();
```

i tried with thread

```
 Browser Browse = new Browser();
 Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(
       new ThreadStart(() =>
       {
          for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++)
          {
              Thread.Sleep(50);
              Browse.Show();
       }
  }
  ));
 backgroundThread.Start();
```

i have an error:

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'webBrowser' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kXUI.png)

Comment: Construct 20 instances of `Browser` and call `Show` on each.

Comment: Why **specifically** do you want to do this with threads?

Comment: You get the error because all operations on types that derive from `Control` must be done on the UI thread. You can't `.Show()` a form in a different thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
For(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    Browser Browse = new Browser();
    Browse.Show()
}
```

You just create more instances and show them...

Edit:

If you must do it with threads look into the SynchronizationContext class. Winforms has the property that the SynchronizationContext.Current always belongs to the UI-thread.